# Hiding div elements within a boothstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to use twitter bootstrap modal and jquery to display the number of divs in a modal based on the choice made in a previous drop-down question.  Other words, if 1 is chosen then only one div in the modal is displayed, if 3 is chosen then three divs in the modal are shown.

**Filter question**:

```
    <select id='species1'>
    <option value="">Number of Species</option>
    <option value="01">1</option>
    <option value="02">2</option>
    <option value="03">3</option>
    <option value="04">4</option>
    <option value="05">5</option>
    </select>

    <div class='btn btn-primary'><button type="button" id="nextbttn">Next</button></div>
```

Here is the **modal script**:

```
<div class="modal hide fade in" style = "width:950px; left:25%; display: none; ">
<div class="modal-header">
<a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</a>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
<table border=1>
<div id="ftype1">
<tr>
<td colspan=3>
<h3><center>ITEM 1</center></h3>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <select id='xtype1'>
    <option value="">Type 1</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    Number of pounds: <input type="text" size="5">
</td>
<td>
    Cost per pound: <input type="text" size="5">
</td>
</tr>
</div> <!-- ftype1 -->

<!------------------------------------------------ -->

<div id="ftype2">
<tr>
<td colspan=3><h3><center>ITEM 2</center></h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <select id='xtype2'>
    <option value="">Type 2</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    Number of pounds: <input type="text" size="5">
</td>
<td>
    Cost per pound: <input type="text" size="5">
</td>
</tr>
</div> <!-- ftype2 -->

<!------------------------------------------------ -->

<div id="ftype3">
<tr>
<td colspan=3><h3><center>ITEM 3</center></h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <select id='xtype3'>
    <option value="">Type 3</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    Number of pounds: <input type="text" size="5">
</td>
<td>
    Cost per pound: <input type="text" size="5">
</td>
</tr>
</div> <!-- ftype3 -->

<div class="modal-footer">
<div class='btn btn-primary'><input name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
<div class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried the following **jquery script**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nextbttn").click(function() {
        var type1 = $('#species1').val();
        if (type1 != '00') {
            if (type1 == '01') {
                $('.modal').modal({
                    backdrop: false
                });
                $('#ftype2').hide();
                $('#ftype3').hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But divs ftype2 and ftype3 are not being hidden.

My question is what the best way to accomplish this??

Thanks
Chris

Comment: There are typos in your markup for the modal window. Could you please fix them, so we know that's not the issue.  For instance, there are a handful of attributes missing the quotations (eg, the `class` for `id="ftype3"`).  Also, where is `nextbttn`?  Since that's the trigger, it would make sense to include its markup and indicate its context.

Comment: Thanks Merv...
Think I caught all the typos and added the code for the button that triggers the modal.

Comment: Nope. `border=1`, `colspan=5` are not valid XML.

Comment: Would this prevent the divs from being hidden?? How can I accomplish what I want??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is fine, but the problem is that you can't have a `div` directly inside a `table`; only in a `td` or `th`.  If you are trying to hide a row in a table, give the rows id's and then select them to hide.

```
<table>
  <tr id="row1"><td><!-- stuff --></td></tr>
  <tr id="row2"><td><!-- stuff --></td></tr>
  <tr id="row3"><td><!-- stuff --></td></tr>
</table>
```

```js
$('#row3').hide(); // hide row3
```